# Saving the state of side menu bar even on refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

Hey Guys I have a side menu bar which collapses when the toggle icon is pressed. The issue that i am facing is that the side menu bar does not keep its state when the page refreshes. I know that local storage is a solution, but was unsuccessful in implementing it. I have posted my JavaScript below and this code works perfectly for closing and opening the menu. I have no idea how to add the local storage. Thanks a lot for your time. Any help is appreciated. I have posted an Edit, that code actually keeps the colour of the last selected menu in the local storage. But when an option is selected the colour goes to the very first option and then comes back to the selected option.

Javascript

```
/*===== EXPANDER MENU  =====*/
const showMenu = (toggleId, navbarId, bodyId) => {
    const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
      navbar = document.getElementById(navbarId),
      bodypadding = document.getElementById(bodyId)
  
    if (toggle && navbar) {
      toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        navbar.classList.toggle('expander')
  
        bodypadding.classList.toggle('body-pd')
      })
    }
  }
  showMenu('nav-toggle', 'navbar', 'body-pd')





  
  
  /*===== COLLAPSE MENU  =====*/
  const linkCollapse = document.getElementsByClassName('collapse__link')
  var i
  
  for (i = 0; i < linkCollapse.length; i++) {
    linkCollapse[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      const collapseMenu = this.nextElementSibling
      collapseMenu.classList.toggle('showCollapse')
  
      const rotate = collapseMenu.previousElementSibling
      rotate.classList.toggle('rotate')
    })
  }
```

edit

```
  /*===== LINK ACTIVE  =====*/
  const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')
  
  function colorLink() {
    linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
    this.classList.add('active')
    
    // Added this to read data attribute
    let this_index = this.getAttribute("data-nav_link_index")
    localStorage.setItem("active_nav_link", this_index)
  }
  linkColor.forEach((l,i) => {
    l.addEventListener('click', colorLink);
    
    // Added this to set data attribute
    l.setAttribute("data-nav_link_index", i);
    
    // Added this to add the active class
    if(localStorage.getItem("active_nav_link")==i){
      l.classList.add("active");
    }else if(localStorage.getItem("active_nav_link")!==null){
      l.classList.remove("active");
    }
  })
```

Comment: Please share your unsuccessful implementation of localstorage, so we can see what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
const showMenu = (toggleId, navbarId, bodyId) => {
  const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
    navbar = document.getElementById(navbarId),
    bodypadding = document.getElementById(bodyId)

  const expanderState = localStorage.getItem("expanderState");
  if (Boolean(expanderState)) {
    navbar.classList.add('expander');
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove('expander');
  }
  if (toggle && navbar) {
    toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
      navbar.classList.toggle('expander')
      if (navbar.classList.contains('expander')) {
        localStorage.setItem("expanderState", true)
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("expanderState", false)
      }
      bodypadding.classList.toggle('body-pd')
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey bro!! Thanks a lot. I seem to have an another problem, and i have posted in the edit. That code saves the colour of the last pressed menu option. But the problem i am facing is that the colour goes to the first option and then comes back to the selected option. Do you know why is this happening? Thankss!!!

Comment: please share HTML content as well.

Comment: As I suspected, you are giving `active` class to the first item, please remove it

Comment: Here working js fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/bmys9pzc/

Comment: Hey Thank you for replying, even when the active is removed , it behaves the same way. When i refresh the colour goes to the first element. :(

Comment: Did you check the solution - https://jsfiddle.net/bmys9pzc/

Comment: Hey @venkatesh, yes the solution seems to be working! Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Venkatesh , but there is another problem, now when i close the webpage and open it again, the menu colour is on the last one i pressed, but the page will be different. Do you know why? Thanks